# Is there any help/ hint while attending trailhead challenge?

Tags: apex, trailhead

I just started learning in Salesforce, I'm getting basic knowledge via super helpful blog i.e **trailhead**. But on a challenge for **Apex**, I got stuck to complete it, I did run my code on **developer Console** and it is giving me the exact result, but when I check my challenge it's giving me the error. Is there any way to get the correct answer?

[image]

Question:

> create an Apex class that inserts a new account named after an
>   incoming parameter. If the account is successfully inserted, the
>   method should return the account record. If a DML exception occurs,
>   the method should return null.
>
> 1. The Apex class must be called AccountHandler and be in the public scope.
> 2. The Apex class must have a public static method called insertNewAccount.
> 3. The method must accept an incoming string as a parameter, which will    be used to create the Account name.
> 4. Insert the account into the system and then return the record.
> 5. The method must also accept an empty string, catch the failed DML and then return null.

Code :

```
public class AccountHandler {
        public static database.SaveResult[] insertNewAccount(String val) {
            try {
                List<Account> acc = new List<Account> { 
                    new Account (Name = val),
                    new Account()
                    };
                database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(acc);
                return results;

            } catch (DmlException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to return the inserted account record not database.SaveResult[].

Your apex class should be like:

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static Account insertNewAccount(String val){
        Account acc = new Account(Name = val);
        try{
            INSERT acc;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        return acc;
    }
}
```